Why does it not matter which way electrons flow in a circuit?
If electrons flow from negative to positive in electron flow, why do we put a resistor in a circuit on the positive side of the conductor before it reaches the LED or light or whatever? I heard people say it does not matter which way electrons flow. In electron flow, shouldn't the electrons reach the LED first?
What really does the work in a circuit? The charge carried by the electrons?

I think this question is more suitable for Electrical Engineering SE.

You can check for yourself that it does not matter if you swapped the relative positions of the resistor and the LED / lamp / whatever. It is difficult to know what precisely you want the answer to.

@VincentThacker, An EE would answer the question in terms of Kirchoff's laws. But Kirchoff will only tell you what to expect if you switch the positions of the LED and the resistor. He won't tell you why. The "why" is in the very much in realm of physics. (So far in, that I'm not able to answer it myself, sorry. I am not a physicist.)

@Ohm'sLawman From the point of view of how circuits are analyzed in physics, there is no difference whether the bulb or resistor comes first. That's why the answer has to come from practical considerations, or a circuit theory that models components beyond RLC.

@Ohm'sLawman just replace "Kirchhoff's laws" with "conservation of charge" and you've got a physics answer.

@VincentThacker, Right but OP expected that energy is carried from the battery to the circuit by electrons and, expected that the electrons give up all of that energy to the first component that they encounter. My training tells me that the circuit behaves differently from that. I could tell OP how to predict the current and, predict how much power will be consumed by either component, but I cannot explain why the circuit behaves in that way. (Probably I'd wave my hands a bit, and then invite them to Google for "Poynting vector.")

Electrons are already in the circuit before you close the switch, much like water is already in the pipe before you turn on the faucet.
Electrons repel each other. Normally this is cancelled by the attraction to the nuclei of nearby atoms. If you force extra electrons onto an object, the electrons get crowded together. Crowding them requires work against the repulsive force. This is the source of energy in a circuit. Voltage is this energy per coulomb of charge.
In a circuit, the battery supplies the energy to force electrons onto one wire. If the circuit was just a wire with no resistance, extra electrons would just move down the wire and back into the battery. An ideal battery would use all its energy up in an instant.
With a resistor, there is a bottleneck. It takes energy to force electrons through a resistor. Electrons get crowded before the resistor, and progressively less crowded as they progress through the resistor.
The electrons before the wire get so crowded that the repulsive forces push back against the battery. The battery cannot push any more electrons into the wire until one leaves through the resistor. This limits the current.
On the other side, they flow freely back to the battery. The energy an electron loses traveling through the resistor is all the energy supplied by the battery. Another way of saying this is the voltage drop across the resistor equals the voltage of the battery.
From the outside, it doesn't matter which way you connect the battery in such a circuit. Electrons will pile up on one side or the other. The current is the same. The voltage changes sign, but has the same magnitude.
In more complex circuits, such as one with two resistors in series, the energy loss and voltage drop is spread among multiple components.
None of this explains the mechanism of a resistor. There are additions to this story with varying degrees of realism. Electrons drift. Electrons bumping into atoms impedes them and this is the source of resistance. This story and the others are just to get the idea. If you want to know how much current, the math is a better tool.
Some devices like LEDs have very little resistance. Without a resistor, a large current would flow, and all of the energy loss would be in the LED. The LED would overheat and burn out very quickly.
With a resistor, the resistor limits the current. Much of the energy loss occurs in the resistor. The energy loss in the LED is smaller.
You might think that if the resistor is after the electrons pass through the LED that the LED would burn out before the electrons get to the resistor. Very few electrons are pushed into the circuit before the resistor takes effect. You can see the process here. Watch electricity hit a fork in the road at half a billion frames per second

First, forget about electrons when analyzing electric current. While you may often model current flow in metals as electron flow, current is a more general concept. The electric currents in your brain that are enabling you to read this are mostly positive ion currents. Even metals can be tricky: beware of aluminum.
Kirchhoff's Current Law tells you that the current entering an electrical network must equal the current leaving it. So, if you want to limit the current, you may limit it either at the entrance or the exit.
It's similar to a garden hose: the valve that controls the flow may be at either end.
As for why the resistor is usually on the positive side, engineers are constantly aware of what could go wrong. With the usual negative common "ground", a "short circuit" is more often to ground than to elsewhere. If the resistor is on the positive side and the junction between the resistor and the diode is shorted to ground, a little extra current flows, but it's harmless. But with the diode on the positive side, an unlimited current flows through the diode, damaging it in this case.

P zone of a LED should have + sign of voltage, and N side negative sign. The LED is a semiconductor device which has electron and holes. The latter is a carrier carrying positive charge. Which is effectively an electron "vacation". An electron and a hole could recombine in a depletion zone, which could give a photon.

I think I'd like to rephrase my question. Basically, we have a circuit with light, a battery, and a resistor. The resistor is put on the positive side of the terminal of the battery before the conductor reaches the light. The light will burn up if there is too much current. Basically, I'm asking what is doing the work in a circuit? The electrons move from the negative to positive side and will reach the light first. Why does the light not burn out if the electrons reached the light first? Is it something else that does work in a circuit?

Which side of the circuit has the resistor  makes no difference to the current in the bulb.

The battery does the work, the electromotive force. What do you mean by burning out light? The current flows in the LED which mean that electrons and holes are moving in the opposite directions in the LED, when they recombine, the light is created.

It does not matter where you put the resistance, however the LED polarization is important. The polarization could be found on the internet depending on the model
